# Which is the better approach to remove the redundant white space in XML [strip-space or indent="no"]?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print my output xml in a single line[when viewed in notepad or other simple text-editor], so as to remove the redundant white-space in my xml file. So which is the better method to follow for that ??

I think there are two options,
1) To use

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
```

2) or to use

```
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Which is more efficient, and why?

some people suggest me to use `indent="no"`,

I believed that strip-space is best suited, but not sure because of suggestions given by others.

To be more elaborated let me take an example:

**Input XML:**

```
<root>
 <node>
   <child1/>
   <child2/>
 </node>
</root>
```

**and the output required is:**

```
<root><node><child1/><child2/></node></root>
```

Comment: Good question. +1 from me. In my answer I tried to explain completely the effect of the two directives and how they interact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In order to eliminate anything that looks like "indentation" it may be necessary (that means there are cases when you need) to use *both* `<xsl:strip-space>`** and **``indent="no"`**.

**Take the simplest example**: you have the identity transformation. Without any of the two methods specified, the transformation will reproduce the white-space-only text nodes from the source XML document. That is, if the source XML document is indented, the transformation will produce indented result, too.

**Now, add to this transformation `<xsl:output indent="no" />`.** This instructs the XSLT processor not to perform "pretty-printing" of its own. However, the whitespace-only nodes from the source XML document are still copied to the output and the result document looks still indented (because the source document is indented).

**Now, as a last step, add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`.** You have specified both methods of preventing white-space-only nodes in the output. What happens? No white-space-only nodes are processed at all by the XSLT processor, *and* it does not indent the output -- you get your desired one-line dense output.

**Finally, make a regression, change the `<xsl:output indent="no" />` to `<xsl:output indent="yes" />`.** The `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` is still there, so no whitespace-only nodes are reproduced in the output. But the XSLT processor obeys the `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` directive and adds whitespace-only text nodes of its own.

**So, from the four possible combinations, only specifying *both*** `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and `<xsl:output indent="no" />` guarantees that no indentation will be caused either from whitespace-only nodes from the source XML document or from the XSLT processors initiative.

**Even this last case, of course, doesn't completely guarantee that the output won't be indented** -- if the XSLT programmer intentionally puts there indentation code such as

`<xsl:text>`

`</xsl:text>`

the output will contain this indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Perfomance differences are best measured. XSLT processor implementations differ, and you should make the test for yourself (though I suspect that worrying over the performance of the one or the other might fall into the "premature optimization" category in this case).

`<xsl:output indent="no" />` might not have the effect you want unless accompanied by

```
<xsl:template match="text(normalize-space()='')" />
```

because if whitespace nodes (the ones between your tags) are not removed, then they will appear in the output at some point, regardless of the "output" setting.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment -- I was still sleepy -- please, delete it.

Why would you code the template, when it means the same as `<xsl:strip-space element="*"/>` ?

Comment: @Dimitre: I meant it solely in conjunction with `<xsl:output indent="no" />`, because `indent="no"` would not be sufficient without any explicit whitespace handling. P.S.: The only one who can delete your comments is yourself. :-) (I know, this has been different in an early version of the site)