# How can I unindent lines in a xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the following XML file content:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
        <title>Red</title>
        <artist>The Communards</artist>
  </cd>
  <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

How can I get the following with any existing tool or XSLT?

```
<catalog>
  <cd><title>Red</title><artist>The Communards</artist></cd>
  <cd><title>Unchain my heart</title><artist>Joe Cocker</artist></cd>
</catalog>
```

I want to do this transformation because I want to remove some records ( 'cd' in this case ) quickly from an xml file. Using the one-line format would help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you surround your attempted XML in <code> tags, so that it shows up? :)

Comment: @syrion - it is better to add 4 spaces before each line (this is what selecting a code block and clicking on the 010101 button does).

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? These files are equivalent. Or do you need a method for canonicalization?

Comment: Why do you need this? Any parser will ignore whitespace between elements.

Comment: Today has been a weird day for XML formatting questions :/

Comment: This is a duplicate. I remember answering this but I can't find it now... Strange requeriment by the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341788/which-is-the-better-approach-to-remove-the-redundant-white-space-in-xml-strip-sp

Comment: @infant programmer: I think not. That's an explanation about `xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:output/@indent`. I meant the exact same question about specific serialization with identation only on root element children.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to do this transformation
>   because I want to remove some records
>   ( 'cd' in this case ) quickly from an
>   xml file. Using the one-line format
>   would help me.

I'm sorry but this is a wrong-headed approach. You want to use XSLT to manipulate the *whitespace* in your document so that it makes it easier to remove the erroneous lines with... something which isn't XSLT? Just remove the lines you don't want with XSLT in the first place!

Basic example (untested but 99% sure this will work for the requirement given):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

  <!-- this is called the identity transform - it will copy the input wholesale -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- this template will provide the exception case for "cd" nodes and effectively remove them -->
  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <!-- do nothing with it! -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Bear in mind this assumes there's a small set of patterns that can match the lines they want to remove. It's possible that they are truly cherry picking what needs to be removed.

Comment: Sure but if there *isn't* any reasonable pattern then there's no advantage to processing it mechanically anyway, and if there *is* there's no point in using a powerful tool to simplify a job for a weaker tool.

Comment: Admittedly, the solution for most users is to change this into a spreadsheet and manipulate the data via Excel. Would that be a more "powerful" tool? :P

Answer (score 2):

Strange requeriment (not semantics differences)... This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('&#xA;', 1 div (position()=last()))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<catalog>
    <cd><title>Red</title><artist>The Communards</artist></cd>
    <cd><title>Unchain my heart</title><artist>Joe Cocker</artist></cd>
</catalog>
```

**Note:** Indentity rule, xsl:strip-space (trims all text nodes), add new line and tab for `cd` and new line for last `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

Tested:

Here's a solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="cd title artist"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key is to ensure the output is not auto-indented, and then specify which elements should have whitespace removed, such as `cd`, `title`, and `artist`.

Comment: This serialize the source in one line.

Comment: @Alejandro I got a different result using the Saxon processor. However the solution you've presented is closer to what they asked for, so I voted you up.

Comment: Because Saxon preserve white space only text nodes and your solution depends on source identation of `cd` (white space only text nodes of `catalog` that you didn't strip)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format arbitrarily large streams (xslt uses an in memory model), you could read it in using a stax event reader and simply write these out again discarding the white space events and inserting a newline event when you encounter a catalog or cd end element event. You could even just remove this step and ignore the cd events that you are not interested in when writing out the result.